# Accessing a Bucket virtual-hosted-style url deprecated? (aws s3)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3, file-upload

Not sure if this is the best place to post this question, please redirect me if this isn't then I will remove the post and post it to the correct location.

I know that recently `amazon s3` has changed their url while accessing files.
It used to be something like `http://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>` or `http://s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket>`

But there's been changes into `http://<bucket>.s3-<aws-region>.amazonaws.com` or `http://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com`, due to this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro
`http://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com` would not be reachable after March 20, 2019, BUT when I use `aws-sdk` in `javascript` to do file upload with `skipper-better-s3` the url I get in return from aws is `http://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<Key>`

If that url is not suppose to be reachable why would aws return such url? (I can still access the file using the url)

If that url is not suppose to be reachable in the near future, am I suppose to add in the `region` myself or modify the url myself instead of using the url returned by aws?

Or it might my code's problem?
Below is my code for the upload

```
        const awsOptions = {  // these fields are different because this uses skipper
            adapter: require('skipper-better-s3'),
            key: aws_access_key,
            secret: aws_secret_key,
            saveAs: PATH,
            bucket: BUCKET,
            s3params: {
                ACL: 'public-read'
            },
        }


        const fieldName = req._fileparser.upstreams[0].fieldName;
        req.file(fieldName).upload(awsOptions, (err, filesUploaded) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            const filesUploadedF = filesUploaded[0]; // F = first file
            const url = filesUploadedF.extra.Location; // image url -> https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<Key>
            console.log(url, 'urlurlurl');
        });
```

`filesUploadedF` would return

```
UploadedFileMetadata {
  fd: '<Key>',
  size: 4337,
  type: 'image/png',
  filename: 'filename.png',
  status: 'bufferingOrWriting',
  field: 'image',
  extra: 
   { ETag: '111111111111111111111',
     Location: 'https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<Key>',
     key: '<key>',
     Key: '<Key>',
     Bucket: '<Bucket>',
     md5: '32890jf32890jf0892j3f',
     fd: '<Key>',
     ContentType: 'image/png' }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation you linked to](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#access-bucket-intro) for `http://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com` style naming says this:

> **Note**
>
> Buckets created in Regions launched after March 20, 2019 are not reachable via the https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com naming scheme.

The wording there is important.  They're only talking about new *regions* brought online after March 20, 2019.

To date, that's only buckets created in Middle East (Bahrain) and Asia Pacific (Hong Kong) regions.

Comment: Ah, I didn't mention in my notes that I actually created the bucket somewhere in Aug or Sept 2019 but that's in oregon.  Since you mentioned the unreachable is only if created in `Middle East (Bahrain) and Asia Pacific (Hong Kong)` then I totally get it.  But then again, know if this would effect the future of the url `http://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com` s3 returned? As it does not have region in it but it seems like they are adding region to most of the s3 urls now

Comment: I can't speak towards AWS's future plans.  I doubt they'll remove the feature for any bucket any time soon, since that would require changing backwards compatibility, and inconvenience a great number of users.  At any rate, they tend to announce such large scale changes months, or even years, in advance, and as far as I'm aware, they've made no such announcements yet.

Comment: I do understand.  Thanks for updating me with the bucket created in those two regions only.  Let me wait for another day or two to see if anyone else know more detail else I will mark yours as correct answer.  But to your opinion, would you use the url (without region) returned by `aws sdk` or you would modify the url to include region?

Comment: I would (and, I do, actually) use the URL returned by the AWS CLI tool or the SDK.  I've not run into a scenario where I need to modify the URL, and I very much doubt these URLs will stop working anytime soon.  That said, if it's a URL a user might see, I try to use [CloudFront with a custom domain name](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/).  Largely because I just feel it looks cleaner to the user.